# When I change username the principal_name column in spring_session table doesn't get changed too

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-session

I am using JDBC Session. I've noticed that when I change the username column (in member table), the principal_name column (in spring_session table) doesn't get updated automatically.

How can I solve this?